Xamarin.UWP: Build URL from own app to launch from ToastButton
I have a Xamarin.Forms app. In Package.appxmanifest of the UWP variant I added
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
      <uap:Protocol Name="my-app">
        <uap:DisplayName>MyApp.UWP</uap:DisplayName>
      </uap:Protocol>
    </uap:Extension>

For this app I declared this route:
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MyRoute), typeof(MyRoute));

MyRoute is the class name for a class derived from ContentPage
Finally, in a background task I send a ToastNotification
 var button = new ToastButton()
      .SetContent("Show")
      .SetBackgroundActivation();

    Uri uri = new Uri("my-app://MyRoute");
    button.SetProtocolActivation(uri);

    var toast = new ToastContentBuilder();
    toast.AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
     .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
     .AddText(message)
     .AddButton(button);
    toast.Show();

my-app starts but it only shows the splash screen. Page MyRoute, however, is not shown as intended. In TaskManager, no process can be seen for my-app.
What is wrong?
Edit: I must add a Host to this Uri. In the examples I always see app but what ist the hostname in my case?

starts but it only shows the splash screen, please check above duplicate answer link end part, you need to process UWP app OnActivated method manually.
